# No credentials found running powershell under a specific user with C# process

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core

I have below code

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Services.CommandHelper
{
    public class PowershellCommandHelper
    {
        private const string ProcessCommand = "powershell.exe";

        public string Exec(string command)
        {
            var result = "";

            var process = new Process
            {
                StartInfo =
                {
                    FileName = ProcessCommand,
                    Arguments = command,
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardInput = false,
                    UserName = "UserName",
                    PasswordInClearText = "Password",
                    Domain = "Domain"
                }
            };

            process.OutputDataReceived += (_, args) => result += args.Data + Environment.NewLine;
            process.ErrorDataReceived += (_, args) => result += args.Data + Environment.NewLine;
            process.Start();
            process.BeginErrorReadLine();
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            process.WaitForExit();
            process.Dispose();

            return result.Trim();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run `echo $env:USERNAME`
It returns the correct user name and also for domain.

But when I run a GIT command it cannot detect any stored credentials and asks for username and password.

The command `cmdkey.exe /list`  returns empty. Also after creating a credentials with command `cmdkey.exe /generic:git....` (these commands return expected results on the actual powershell on windows with the user logon but not using the above C# code)

It seems that the process is running in an isolated mode.

What's going on and how can I fix this?

Comment: Why are you running `powershell.exe`?  From a .NET app you should use the [System.Management.Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) library to work directly with PowerShell classes, etc.

Comment: Because the purpose is to run a powershell script file and I wondering why this happening?

Comment: You can run PS1 scripts using the automation library.

Comment: I didn't test that. I'll test that. I wanna know why such thing is happening?